# Work with Git Tool - Submodules with PhpStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm, git-submodules

Can somebody explain me.. I don't know a lot of knowledge with Git Submodules and PhpStorm I am working with one project, that has a lot of submodules and I have do add new ones and delete others, others get modified and have to be updated and there are all in one main project, I have to update the main project as well I don't know how to checkout one submodule in the project and make a commit (should I push it too?) how that changes in the main project? another commit should be taken for this submodul and for that one more commit ? .. I have never done this before.. and I have to do it now.

Please how can this with PhpStorm be done, not with git commands, it is very sensible.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you have multiple questions. 
First of all, I would like to note that you need to make sure that you are 100% sure what submodules should be deleted and which should stay untouched. Regrettably, we cannot advise on which of them should be removed and whether they must be pushed or not.

If you have a remote repository that already has some submodules added and some removed, then please click on **"Update project" under VCS menu** - it will update root and submodules in your project. For more please see here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sync-with-a-remote-repository.html#update

If you need to commit only one submodule, then please go to VCS | Commit and in commit dialog check submodule folder. If you need to push it to remote repository, you can click on an **arrow next to "Commit"** button and pick **"Commit and Push"**. Otherwise, if you want to commit the whole project - check the root folder.